# How to use array of checkbox and array of text areas/dropdowns in angular js table with ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, textarea, html-select

I have a use case where i need to store which employee is staying in which hotel of particular city for some data processing. I have populated cities in one drop down, once user selects particular city, hotels from that city will be populated in another drop down.

If any hotel is not listed on drop downs, user need to select the checkbox so one text area will appear beside drop downs where user can enter hotel name     for that employee and drop downs for that particular employee will be disabled. I was able to handle this stuff initially when there was only 3 cities. But now cities and hotels are increasing and i want to make a dynamic table for this.

So i have written below code,

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="employee in department.employees">
    <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name="selectedChecks[]" data-ng-model="check" 
        data-ng-change="ShowHide()"/>
    </td>
    <td>{{employee.empId}}.{{employee.empname}}</td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="selectedCities[]" data-ng-model="hotelsource" 
            data-ng-options="city.cityname for city in cities" data-ng-disabled="check">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
    </td> 
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="selectedHotels[]" data-ng-disabled="check" data-ng-model="option" 
                data-ng-options="hotel.hotelname for hotel in hotelsource.hotels">
        <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div data-ng-show="ruleArea">
            <textarea id="txtArea" name="txtAreas[]" rows="3" cols="70"></textarea>
        </div>
    </td>
```

Initially i was hiding text areas as below and there were no array names as shown above,

```
$scope.ShowHide1 = function () {
    //If DIV is visible it will be hidden and vice versa.
    $scope.ruleArea1 = $scope.check1;
};
$scope.ShowHide2 = function () {
    //If DIV is visible it will be hidden and vice versa.
    $scope.ruleArea2 = $scope.check2;
};
$scope.ShowHide3 = function () {
    //If DIV is visible it will be hidden and vice versa.
    $scope.ruleArea3 = $scope.check3;
};
```

But now with above table piece of code and only single ShowHide() function, i am able to disable the drop downs but text area hide-show isn't working.

I am very new to Angular JS, So can anyone help me on how to showhide this text areas and how to get this selected values?

Comment: define ng-model for element as array

Comment: @hadiJZ any example please?

Comment: please display employees object.

Comment: @hadiJZ {"empId":"emp123","empname":"abc","address":"address1","level":"level1"}

Comment: do you see my answer??

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get the index of your array in the ng-repeat with $index.

Try something like this:

In your html

```
<input type='checkbox' 
       data-ng-model="check[$index]" 
       data-ng-change="ShowHide($index)"/>  // model and change function with $index
<div data-ng-show="ruleArea[$index]">       // get value for this index
```

In your angular code

```
$scope.ShowHide = function (index) {
    $scope.ruleArea[index] = $scope.check[index];   // ruleArea and check with index
};
```

To bind the values to the specific employee in department.employees, use ng-model="employee.hotelsource", ng-model="employee.option" etc. So later if you have an employee from the department.employees list you can access employee.hotelsource.

Alternative: If you need the data separate then initialize an array and bind by the index.

```
$scope.employeeData = [];

ng-model="employeeData[$index].hotelsource"
```

So later you have an array with the values that you can access by the employee index.

Comment: Do i need to define index somewhere? Getting below error after doing this <br/>  Error: Va(...) is undefined
Wa.prototype.objectIndex/<.assign@http://localhost:8080/myapp/dist/js/lib/angular.min.js:161:218

Comment: $index is automatically present in an ng-repeat: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat you probably need to init the arrays like $scope.check = []; $scope.ruleArea = [];

Comment: Thanks, half the answer done. Added arrays as suggested, +1 for that. Now, any clue how can i read those arrays of drop downs in js?

Comment: Do you mean the hotelsource etc? You should bind these values to the employee, e.g. ng-model="employee.hotelsource" so later in your list of employees you can select the hotelsource from the employee.

Comment: Thanks lisa, but unfortunately it didn't worked out for me, i added one method on ng-change for both of the drop-downs and passed index & the ng-model value to it. Then stored those values in an array in controller.js for future processing.

Comment: Hey, I adapted my answer. If this works for you it would be great to mark the answer as correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

try this. and also for other field similar address define ng-model.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  
   $scope.data ={
     "employees":[
      {"empId":"emp123","empname":"abc","address":"address1","level":"level1"},
        {"empId":"emp127","empname":"abc1","address":"address2","level":"level2"}
       
     ]  
   };
  
  $scope.check = [true,true];
  
 
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <table>
     <tr data-ng-repeat="employee in data.employees">
       <td>
        <input type='checkbox' name="selectedChecks[]" data-ng-model="check[$index]" ng-change="ShowHide()" 
        data-ng-change="ShowHide()"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div data-ng-show="check[$index]">
           <textarea id="txtArea" name="txtAreas[$index]" ng-model="employee.address" rows="3" cols="70"> </textarea>
        </div>
             
    </td>
     </tr>
   </table> 
    <span>{{data|json}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what i want to do is show/hide text area on check/uncheck of checkbox.

Comment: i put sample code. this code may be road map for complete your code.

Comment: Yup, got solution for this. But how can i read those arrays of drop downs in js?